# firebase functions group deployment error (undefined)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to deploy firebase functions index.js file. If I try to deploy a single functions, like (firebase deploy --only functions:phaseStart), it works well. However, if I deploy the whole functions folder, like (firebase deploy --only functions), the error comes out. I deployed this functions just yesterday and none of these happened. Is there some problem in index.js file? or am I deploying so much functions?

The error code is below.

```
+  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
+  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged functions (46.47 KB) for uploading
+  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  functions: updating Node.js 8 function roomRemoved(asia-northeast1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 8 function gameStart(asia-northeast1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 8 function phaseStart(asia-northeast1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 8 function nightAction(asia-northeast1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 8 function vote(asia-northeast1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 8 function userCreated(asia-northeast1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 8 function userDeleted(asia-northeast1)...
!  functions[userDeleted(asia-northeast1)]: Deployment error.
undefined
!  functions[phaseStart(asia-northeast1)]: Deployment error.
undefined
!  functions[vote(asia-northeast1)]: Deployment error.
undefined
!  functions[gameStart(asia-northeast1)]: Deployment error.
undefined
!  functions[roomRemoved(asia-northeast1)]: Deployment error.
undefined
!  functions[nightAction(asia-northeast1)]: Deployment error.
undefined
+  functions[userCreated(asia-northeast1)]: Successful update operation.


Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        gameStart
        nightAction
        phaseStart
        roomRemoved
        userDeleted
        vote


To try redeploying those functions, run:
    firebase deploy --only functions:gameStart,functions:nightAction,functions:phaseStart,functions:roomRemoved,functions:userDeleted,functions:vote


To continue deploying other features (such as database), run:
    firebase deploy --except functions

Error: Functions did not deploy properly.
```

Also I found auditlog on the firebase console.

```
{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","status":{"code":13,"message":"INTERNAL"},"authenticationInfo":{"principalEmail":"blabla"},"requestMetadata":{"requestAttributes":{},"destinationAttributes":{}},"serviceName":"cloudfunctions.googleapis.com","methodName":"google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction","resourceName":"projects/blabla/locations/asia-northeast1/functions/gameStart"}
```

And this is one of my functions.

```
exports.userDeleted = functions
  .region('asia-northeast1')
  .auth.user().onDelete(async user => {
    return db.collection('uid_list').doc(user.uid).delete().catch(e => {
      console.error(e.code)
      console.log(e.message)
    })
  })
```

Comment: Could you provide at least one of your functions.

Comment: Did you watched the async await videos from Doug Stevenson on YouTube?

Comment: @ConstantinBeer Oh that async is somethong I put accidentally.  Without it, it seems normal at all, right?

Comment: I'm not really sure, but I think you can leave out the `return`. But don't know if that will fix your problem. Never really used triggers in firebase before.

Comment: it's happening to me from yesterday. not sure why. but as a workaround, i can deploy one by one functions (e.g. `firebase deploy --only functions:<function>` ) .

Comment: ah, i just also found out i'm using `asia-northeast1` too. so, maybe, something is happening in the region?

Comment: @MasatomoNakano I reported this issue to firebase team. They said to update my firebase-tools as the latest version 7.2.4, but nothing changed. I sent them debug log file. There's something wrong with the functions server I guess.